# How to change the width of the html selector with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In my CSS I set the width of the html like this:

```
html {width: 1000px; }
```

I would like to be able to change this width dynamically with javascript similar to setting the style.width of an element.  The window.document node doesn't have a style property and I can't find the width anywhere.

Where in the DOM is the 1000px stored and can I change it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get it like:

```
document.documentElement
```

or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
```

or even:

```
document.body.parentElement
```

---

So to get the CSS width, just do:

```
document.documentElement.style.width
```

---

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement

> Returns the Element that is the root element of the document (for example, the <html> element for HTML documents).

Comment: Perfect!  That was it.  Thank you, Shomz.

Answer (score 0):

I like this way, personally

```
document.body.parentNode.style.width = "1000px";
```